# Java Fx setOnMouseDragged To Slow

Tags: canvas, javafx, mouseevent, mouselistener

I want to create my own paint, however for someone reason when i move the mouse to fast instead of creating a line, i create a bunch dots.

```
public class ExtractController {

@FXML
private Canvas canvas;

private GraphicsContext gc ;

public void initialize() {
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
        double size = 5;
        double x = e.getX();
        double y = e.getY();

        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    });
}
}
```

[image]

It's there anyway to make the mouseDragged event to trigger faster? or is there a other way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: No: it will be triggered when it is triggered. You need to remember the previous location and draw a line, instead of just filling rectangles.

Comment: So u are saying, instead of drawing dots i save the 1st position and the 2position and keep drawing lines. Let me try and thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think you understand what I mean.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't control how quickly the mouse events are received (apart from anything, it depends on how fast the user presses the mouse).

Instead of drawing individual dots, draw lines from the previous position:

```
public class ExtractController {

    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    private GraphicsContext gc ;

    private double lastX ;
    private double lastY ;

    public void initialize() {
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            lastX = e.getX();
            lastY = e.getY();
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
            double size = 5;
            double x = e.getX();
            double y = e.getY();

            gc.setLineWidth(size);
            gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
            gc.strokeLine(lastX, lastY, x, y);
            lastX = x ;
            lastY = y ;
        });
    }

}
```